# Show that a random variable is not dominated

Tags: probability-theory

Let $((0,1], \mathcal{B}_{(0,1]}, \lambda)$ be a probability space, and define
$$
X_n = n 1_{(0,1/n]}
$$
This is an example where $\lim E(X_n) \neq E( \lim X_n)$, and the dominated convergence theorem doesn't apply because $X_n$ can't be dominated by an integral random variable.

I can see intuitively that this random variable can't be dominated by an integrable random variable; $X(\omega) = 1/\omega$ "connects the dots" and its expectation isn't finite. However, how could one prove that $X_n$ can't possibly dominated by an integrable random variable? I was thinking about a proof by contradiction, but I didn't succeed.

I suppose that one way to prove it is by saying that since 1) $\lim E(X_n) \neq E( \lim X_n)$, 2) $X_n \rightarrow 0$, and 3) DCT doesn't apply, we can't have domination (the result doesn't follow, so at least one premise of the DCT must be false, which in this case is domination). But I was looking for something more "constructive".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X_n\leqslant X$ for every $n$, then $X\geqslant Y$ where $Y=\sup\limits_{n\geqslant1} X_n$. Note that
$$
Y=\sum_{n\geqslant1}n\mathbf 1_{(1/(n+1),1/n]},
$$
hence
$$
E[Y]=\sum_{n\geqslant1}n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n+1},
$$
which is infinite. One sees that $Y$ is not integrable, and that neither is any dominating random variable $X$.